# Netflix on Raspberry Pi (2014 version)

Tags: streaming-video

It is October 2014 and the lastest version of Chrome (I think it is version 38) finally supports Netflix **on Linux**. Yey, HTML5!

Now that we have finally overcome that problem, is there any news on how to watch Netflix on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Sadly, navigating to netflix with epiphany eventually leads to an "unknown error occurred" Player error.

Comment: you can run chromium(open source part of chrome) on the raspberry pi but it is painfully slow.

Comment: Running resource-intensive browser or UI elements will never be a strong suit of RPi. Getting it to serve any reasonably js-y web content is painful enough. Recognize what it is and what it is not.

Comment: I never asked how to run Chrome on Raspberry Pi. I just offered some context to the current situation about Netflix and Linux. I do not care if I get to see Netflix on Chrome, Firefox, or Vi :P

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run Netflix if you use OpenElec or RaspBmc as your OS. Each is a variant of XBMC which has an addon for Netflix. I am currently using RaspBmc to view other shows from my B+.

**Edit**:
The best, and, most straight forward way to accomplish this is to purchase (currently $19) a copy of [PlayOn](http://www.playon.tv/) to run on a pc in your home network.  PlayOn has a Netflix channel built in.  Once you've loaded PlayOn on your pc, you can access the shows from your Pi via XBMC's UPnP support.  This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJFnARZijeI) explains the entire setup, as well as, [this article](http://mymediaexperience.com/raspberry-pi-xbmc-with-raspbmc/).  I have a lifetime license for PlayOn and it works seamlessly.

Comment: I already have tried RaspBmc. Mind explaining how can I see NetFlix with it?

Comment: @Dbugger Updated XBMC/NetFlix answer.

Answer (score -1):

Check out our experience about netflix! It may help somehow)) Described here (in my blog post) **[https://eltechs.com/netflix-raspberry-pi](https://eltechs.com/netflix-raspberry-pi/?utm_source=raspberrypi_stackexchange&utm_medium=run-wine-on-raspberry-pi&utm_campaign=forums)**

Comment: Nice one. Too bad it does not come for free. :-/

Comment: @kwasmich Well, neither does PlayOn, and there's more in x86 world than just netflix.

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.